# What is wrong with my Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: python, implementation, path-finding, dijkstra

It returns the values (21, 2, 0, -1, -1 etc), when it should actually only return the origin and the target, as there is a clear path between both. I can't understand what I've done wrong.
Note: The code just seems to return the closest node to the origin (pathfinding object), then the target (0), regardless of the location of the origin.
Update: The new code (now shown below in place of the other code) just returns the target node as the next in the sequence, regardless of whether that particular path is obstructed or not.

```
def Dijkstra(NodeDistanceApart, Target):
    #finds the shortest path according to node distances


    #0 - Initializes values for pathfinding
    NodeDistanceFromOrigin = [10000.0] * NUMBEROFNODES
    NodeSolved = [False] * NUMBEROFNODES
    NodeArcSet = [[-1] * NUMBEROFNODES for x in range(NUMBEROFNODES)]
    ClosestNode = 0
    PreviousNode = 0

    #1 - Sets the origin node (the NPC node) and the target node (the player node) values
    NodeSolved[NUMBEROFNODES2] = True
    NodeDistanceFromOrigin[NUMBEROFNODES2] = 0
    NodeArcSet[NUMBEROFNODES2][0] = NUMBEROFNODES2

    #2 - finds the shortest path
    while NodeSolved[0] == False:
        ClosestNode = 0
        for n in range(NUMBEROFNODES):
            if NodeSolved[n] == True:#loops through nodes, if a node is solved, find connected nodes
                for i in range(NUMBEROFNODES):
                    if NodeSolved[i] == False and NodeDistanceApart[n][i] < 10000:#loops through nodes, if a node is solved or unconnected, then ignore it
                        if (NodeDistanceFromOrigin[n] + NodeDistanceApart[n][i]) < NodeDistanceFromOrigin[i]:
                            NodeDistanceFromOrigin[i] = NodeDistanceFromOrigin[n] + NodeDistanceApart[n][i]
                        if NodeDistanceFromOrigin[i] < NodeDistanceFromOrigin[ClosestNode]:
                            ClosestNode = i
                            PreviousNode = n
        NextInArray = -1
        n = 0
        while NextInArray == -1:#finds the next unused index in the array for a nodes arc set
            if NodeArcSet[ClosestNode][n] == -1:
                NextInArray = n
            n = n + 1
        NodeSolved[ClosestNode] = True
        NodeArcSet[ClosestNode] = NodeArcSet[PreviousNode]
        NodeArcSet[ClosestNode][NextInArray] = ClosestNode
    print(NodeArcSet[0])
    return NodeArcSet
```

Comment: ugh.  please read [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the whole algorithm because there is a serious error with the implementation.

The problem is this line

```
NodeArcSet = [[-1] * NUMBEROFNODES] * NUMBEROFNODES
```

This creates NUMBEROFNODES pointers to the same array [[-1]*NUMBEROFNODES].

```
>>> a=[[0]*2]*2
>>> a
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]=1
>>> a
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

What I do to fix this issue is something like

```
NodeArcSet = [[-1] * NUMBEROFNODES for x in xrange(NUMBEROFNODES)] 
                     # In python 3 you should use range instead of xrange.
```

Comment: That seems fair enough, thank you for it. I'll implement that tonight and post the results.

Comment: Ok, it seems to have corrected some errors, so thank you for that, but the pathfinding just doesn't work at all now. All the algorithm does is move the object directly towards the target, even with obstacles in the way. I'll update the code.